# SQL Server - Insert XML to every row in a column

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have 2 tables

- `Customer` (CustomerID int, Name varchar(20), OrderHistory xml)
- `Order` (OrderID int, CustomerID int, OrderDate date)

And I would like to insert into every row in `OrderHistory` column, an `OrderDate` of that `Customer` based on `CustomerID`.

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE Customer
SET OrderHistory = (SELECT OrderDate
                    FROM Order
                    WHERE CustomerID = 1
                    FOR XML AUTO)
WHERE CustomerID = 1
```

However, I have to change `CustomerID` for every new customer. Is there any way to insert into every customer at once ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying `UPDATE ... FROM ...` construct to your initial SQL to make it update all customer data at once should be straightforward :

```
UPDATE Customer
SET OrderHistory = 
    (SELECT OrderDate
    FROM Order o
    WHERE o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    FOR XML AUTO)
FROM Customer c
```

Answer (score 0):

For Updating table via using Join another table use the next Approach:

```
UPDATE A
SET foo = B.bar
FROM TableA A
JOIN TableB B
ON A.col1 = B.colx
WHERE ...
```

So the update query will be as next:

```
UPDATE A
SET OrderHistory = B.OrderDate
FROM Customer A
JOIN Order B
ON A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
```

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out:

```
DECLARE
@count int
SET
@count = 0
UPDATE Customer
WHILE @count < (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Customer)
BEGIN
SET OrderHistory = (SELECT
    OrderDate
FROM
    Order
WHERE CustomerID = @count
FOR XML AUTO)
WHERE CustomerID = @count
SET @count = @count + 1
END
```

Comment: Slow because you're running a select count in a loop, assumes that customer number has no gaps, and lastly unnecessarily uses a loop. There are many more far superior suggestions here - it would be a good idea to learn from them.